# What's the difference in: Import module & From module import module?

Tags: python, random, module

Here is my program that takes a list a words and sorts them from longest to shortest and breaks ties with the random module.

```
import random  
def sort_by_length1(words):
    t = []
    for word in words:
        t.append((len(word), random(), word))

    t.sort(reverse = True)


    res = []
    for length, randomm, word in t:
        res.append(word)
    return res
```

I get this error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

But when I do: `from module import module` It works?? Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random` module has a `random` function. When you do `import random` you get the module, which obviously is not callable. When you do `from random import random` you get the function which is callable. That's why you don't see the error in the second case.

You can test this in your REPL.

```
>>> import random
>>> type(random)
module
>>> from random import random
>>> type(random)
builtin_function_or_method
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import random
```

is equivalent to

```
import random as _random
random = _random.random
```

so if you only do

```
import random
```

you have to use

```
random.random()
```

instead of

```
random()
```

Comment: whereas it is indeed confusing, especially to new python learners, that a module is having exactly the same name as one of its methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import random
```

is equivalent to:

```
import random          # assigns the module random to a local variable
random = random.random # assigns the method random in the module random
```

You can't call the module itself, but you can call its method [random](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.random). Module and method having the same name is only confusing to humans; the syntax makes it clear which one you mean.

Comment: So why doesn't just import random work? I'm fairly new to this language so I'm having a little difficulty understanding what that mean.

Comment: @G.G Because `import random` allows you to access the imported *module* under the name `random`. You can't call a module.

Comment: A module is an entirely different concept from a function. It's just a coincidence that in this case both share the same name.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke the command,

```
import random
```

You are importing a reference the module, which contains all the functions and classes. This reference is now in your namespace. The goodies inside the random module can now be accessed by `random.func(arg1, arg2)`.

This allows you to perform the following calls to the random module:

```
>>> random.uniform(1, 5)
2.3904247888685806
>>> random.random()
0.3249685500172673
```

So in your above code when the python interpreter hits the line,

```
t.append((len(word), random(), word))
```

The `random` is actually referring to the module name and throws an error because the module name isn't callable, unlike the function you're looking for which is inside.

If you were to instead invoke

```
from random import random
```

You are adding a reference in your name space to the function `random` within the module `random`. You could have easily have said `from random import randint` which would let you call `randint(1, 5)`  without a problem.

I hope this explains things well.